# Uploading to Azure Blob Storage with extra parameters in Web api

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, postman, azure-blob-storage, multipartform-data

I am using the following code to upload video to blob in Web Api, and it works fine when I am upload just video.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/v1/Video/upload")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPostVideo()
    {
        var Desc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Desc"];
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        CloudStorageAccount _sourceStorageAccount = null;
        var accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountName"].ToString();
        var accountKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountKey"].ToString();
        string Container = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VideoContainer"].ToString();

        _sourceStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = _sourceStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer videoContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);

        try
        {
            var provider = new AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(videoContainer);
            var filename = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault().LocalFileName;
            return Ok("Video Uploaded Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("Some thing went Wrong" + ex);
        }
    }


   public class AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : 
   MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
   {
    private readonly CloudBlobContainer _blobContainer;
    private readonly string[] _supportedMimeTypes = { "video/mp4","video/mov" };

    public AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer)
        : base("azure")
    {
        _blobContainer = blobContainer;
    }

    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {


            if (!_supportedMimeTypes.Contains(headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower()))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Only jpeg and png are supported");
            }

            // Generate a new filename for every new blob
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName + ".mp4");

            if (headers.ContentType != null)
            {
                // Set appropriate content type for your uploaded file
                blob.Properties.ContentType = headers.ContentType.MediaType;

            }

            this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, blob.Name));

            return blob.OpenWrite();
      }
  }
```

However when I try to send text value in form-data using PostMan it gives error.

```
 System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type 'AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider' threw an exception.
```

I am aware that `GetStream()` is getting called multiple times in `AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` class. I am not really sure if i am missing some thing or not.

Comment: Can you check if the folder to where the response is being written out has necessary permissions for your application to write.
Or check the folder is already exist or not.

Comment: @JoeyCai no its not the permission issue I think the issue is `GetStream() ` is called two times if my request has two fields in above case i am sending two values one is video file and other one is plain text and when the `GetStream()` gets called for second time it tries to get stream from the plain text and throw exception.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: @BruceChen Hey i just tried your comment it worked great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I have checked your code and found that the `ContentType` for the **txt** data is null, so `_supportedMimeTypes.Contains(headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower())` would throw the exception, you could debug your code to check this issue.

For your requirement, you could change your `GetStream` method as follows:

```
public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
{
    // For form data, Content-Disposition header is a requirement
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = headers.ContentDisposition;

    if (contentDisposition != null)
    {
        //file
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName))
        {
            if (!_supportedMimeTypes.Contains(headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower()))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Only .mp4 and .mov are supported");
            }

            // Generate a new filename for every new blob
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName + ".mp4");

            if (headers.ContentType != null)
            {
                // Set appropriate content type for your uploaded file
                blob.Properties.ContentType = headers.ContentType.MediaType;

            }

            this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, blob.Name));
            //I also define my AzureBlobMultipartFileData instead of MultipartFileData to show the BlobUrl
            //this._blobFileData.Add(new AzureBlobMultipartFileData(headers, blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri));

            return blob.OpenWrite();
        }
        else
            return new MemoryStream();

    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Did not find required 'Content-Disposition' header field in MIME multipart body part..");
}
```

Moreover, in order to extract the txt content, you also need to override the `ExecutePostProcessingAsync` method under your `AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read the non-file contents as form data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < Contents.Count; index++)
        {
            HttpContent formContent = Contents[index];
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = formContent.Headers.ContentDisposition;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName))
            {
                string formFieldName = contentDisposition.Name.Trim('\"');
                string formFieldValue = await formContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                FormData.Add(formFieldName, formFieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

For your action, after construct the `AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider`, you need to manually read the content as follows:

```
var provider = new AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(container);

await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

I just return the response as follows:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
{
    fileData = provider.BlobFileData.Select(f => f.BlobUrl),
    formData = provider.FormData.AllKeys.Select(d => new { key = d, value = provider.FormData[d] })
}, "application/json");
```

**TEST:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For retrieving the file extension from the MIME type, you could leverage [MimeTypeMap](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap) as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("audio/wav -> " + MimeTypeMap.GetExtension("audio/wav")); // ".wav"
```